# Matlab: Solving homogenous set of linear equations based on Kirchhoff's circuit laws

Tags: circuit-analysis, matlab, kirchhoffs-laws

I have got the following equivalent circuit of a common source amplifier from which I want to determine the expression for the voltage gain A = VD/VG.

[image]

Because I have pretty much more difficult circuits to solve, I want to use a systematic approach instead of calculating the result manually. So, with the definitions

[image]

I thought the easiest way is to define the Kirchhoff's loop equations

[image]

and the Kirchhoff's junction equations

[image]

Together with the equations from Ohm's law

[image]

and the input impedance

[image]

I stated the coefficient matrix C in Matlab:

[image]

However, because it is a homogenous set of equations Matlab only shows the trivial result (V = 0).

Am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Isn't this more a question as to how do I use Matlab rather than a proper EE question?

Comment: you are multiplying an inverse of  a matrix with a zero vector! What do you expect?

Comment: Of course, doing so I expect the result to be zero. The question is: How do I have to change my matrix / Is my ansatz fundamentally wrong?

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel: https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3443-scam-a-tool-for-symbolically-solving-circuit-equations . It may not be a perfect fit regarding models for transistors and such but studying the source will certainly show you a possible solution.